# PHP - OnClick UPDATE MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to select how many clicks a certain user has on that day:

```
$res=$db->Query("SELECT `today_clicks` AS total_subs FROM user_clicks WHERE `uid` = '".$data['id']."' AND `module` = \"ysub\""); 
$r=mysql_fetch_object($res);
echo $r->total_subs;
if($db->GetNumRows($res) == 0){
echo "0";
}
```

I would like to add a button if the above query number is above 50 to perform 2 MySQL updates which are:

```
$db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET ``premium`='".$premium."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
$db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET  `fbbonus` =  '1' WHERE  `users`.`id` ='".$data['id']."';");
```

But I have no idea how to only run those queries on a button click and if they have 50 + clicks.

Comment: A 'button'? Or do you just want to run those two commands when the click count is > 50?

Comment: No they have to click a button or something similar saying claim reward.

Answer (score 0):

I will not write out the entire code for you because that is not the point of this site. I will, however, tell you how you could do it.

- Create an anchor with `someID`
- Send an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to the page that holds your PHP (the code for the query) and if the result is greater than 50 (check using [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)) - note, deprecated - , simply continue in the script and run the next two queries
- Return to ajax script